# Remove empty line after Replace in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have many classes and these classes have properties with attribute `[WordColumn("Xxx", 1, typeof(string))]`. E.g:

```
[JsonObject("Сотрудник")]
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("firstName")]
    [WordColumn("Имя", 1, typeof(string))]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("lastName")]
    [WordColumn("Фамилия", 1)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    // ... other properties are omitted for the brevity
}
```

What I want is a regular expression that can delete all text that starts from `[WordColumn` and ends with `)]` and delete empty line which can be left after deletion.

I've tried to write the following regex and it finds all `WordColumn`:

```
\[WordColumn.*?\]
```

However, when I use it in Visual Studio with **Find and Replace**, then **Replace in Files**, tick **Use Regular Expression**, I leave **Replace** empty. Then after it leaves empty spaces after **Replaces**:

```
[JsonObject("Сотрудник")]
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("firstName")]
                               // <- here the empty line remains
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("lastName")]
                              // <- here the empty line remains
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I am doing this in Visual Studio 2019 with `Replace` button.

Is it possible to remove this empty lines after `[WordColumn...]` was replaced?

Comment: Try `\[WordColumn.*?\]\r?\n?`

Comment: @AndersonPimentel  Thanks for the answer! Should I leave **Replace** text box empty?

Comment: Yes, you should leave it empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex from @AndersonPimentel comment but with a small change (add `^[\t ]*` to remove spaces)

```
^[\t ]*\[WordColumn.*?\]\r?\n
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Should I leave **Replace** empty?

Comment: Thanks! It works! But could you say please, how it deletes empty spaces?:)

Comment: `^` Matches the beginning of the string. `\t` Matches a TAB character. `  `  Matches a SPACE character. `*` Match 0 or more of the preceding token

Answer (score 1):

The proper regular expression for both, Visual Studio for Windows and for Mac, would be

```regex
\[WordColumn.*?\]\s*
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Should I leave **Replace** empty?

Comment: yes, leave it empty